# Applying regex on each item of a list in Python

Tags: python, regex, loops, for-loop

If I apply this regex:

```
re.split(r"(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", "janu")
```

on the string "janu", it gives the following result: `['', 'j', 'anu']`

Now I want to apply this regex on the following list to get the similar results for each item as above. Can a `for` loop be used, and if yes, how?

```
lista = ['janu', 'manu', 'tanu', 'banu']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> from re import split
>>> lista = ['janu', 'manu', 'tanu', 'banu']
>>> [split("(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", x)[1]+"doc" for x in lista]
['jdoc', 'mdoc', 'tdoc', 'bdoc']
>>>
```

---

**Edit regarding comment:**

This will work:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> lista = ['janu', 'manu', 'tanu', 'banu']
>>> listb = []
>>> for item in lista:
...     data = split("(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", item)
...     listb.append(data[2]+data[1]+"doc")
...
>>> listb
['anujdoc', 'anumdoc', 'anutdoc', 'anubdoc']
>>>
```

Comment: Oh my god, there was only a 10 second delay between our two answers.

Comment: @randomusername - Yea, that seems to happen alot on SO.  10 secs isn't the best though.  I've sometimes posted simultaneously with someone else.

Comment: Is there any other way? because it gives nested lists. I have to do an other operation on the list obtained from first item. after completing it, the regexp should move to the second item, and carry on...

Comment: lista = ['janu', 'manu', 'tanu', 'banu'] 
after applying this re.split(r"(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", lista), the regex shouldn't move to the next item until I concatenate the string at index[2] and the suffix doc.
for example:
first step:
['', 'j', 'anu']
index[1]+doc = jdoc

second step:
['', 'm', 'anu']
index[1]+doc = mdoc

Third Step:
['', 't', 'anu']
index[1]+doc = tdoc

Fourth step:
['', 'b', 'anu']
index[1]+doc = bdoc

ultimately the result should look "jdok mdoc tdok bdoc"

Comment: @Coddy - Your end result doesn't match your explanation.  Do you want "doc" placed at the end or a back-and-forth of "dok" and "doc"?

Comment: @Coddy - Good, that's the easy one. :)  See my edit.

Comment: Last thing before it's over. Why this doesn't work when it comes to concatenating 3 strings([2]+[1]+"doc")?: compare this with yours above >>> [split("(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", x)[2]+[1]+"doc" for x in lista]

Comment: @Coddy - Because `+[1]` is invalid syntax.  My edit will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the list comprehension

```
[re.split(r"(^[^aeiou]+)(?=[aeiouy])", i) for i in list]
```

You *can* use a for loop but this is considered the **pythonic** way to do things.

Comment: Is there any other way? because it gives nested lists. I have to do an other operation on the list obtained from first item. after completing it, the regexp should move to the second item, and should carry on until the last item in the original list(lista)...